# How to minimize sum of squares?

Tags: calculus

> For the data given in the figure, find $x$ to minimize $t$.
>   [Minimize the sum of the squares of the times on each leg to avoid square roots. $t^2=\frac{d^2}{s^2}$]
>
> Total distance $A\text{ to }B = 18$
>   Minimize: $t_1^2+t_2^2$
>
> [image]

What would be the steps for solving this problem? I don't understand which parts I am supposed to differentiate and which parts I am supposed to substitute.

Comment: I didnt get the question could you please ellaborate more on it

Comment: I don't understand it, myself.

Comment: There is no need to differentiate anything, you have been asked to minimize $t_1^\color{red}{2} + t_2^\color{red}{2}$ instead of $t_1 + t_2$. When you express $t_1^2$ and $t_2^2$ in terms of $x$ using Pythagorean theorem, you get a quadratic polynomial in $x$ to minimize. You can derive the minimum value by completing squares. Try that yourself, it is not that hard and see whether you get the correct minimum $\frac{235783}{45325} \approx 5.20205$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very informal solution that uses Wolfram Alpha and physics:

Light takes the path of minimum time (this is called Fermat's principle).

Consider the following scenario:

[image: Snell's Law]

A ray of light passes from one medium to another medium. 
Snell's law states that $\displaystyle\frac{\sin\theta_1}{v_1}=\frac{\sin\theta_2}{v_2}$, where $v_1$ and $v_2$ represent the speeds of light in the respective media.

So, let's replace $v_1$ with 5 and $v_2$ with 7.

Then we have the following equation:

$\displaystyle\frac{\sin\theta_1}{5}=\frac{\sin\theta_2}{7}$

We know $\theta_1=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)$ and that $\theta_2=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{18-x}{3}\right)$

So, $\displaystyle\frac{\sin\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)\right)}{5}=\frac{\sin\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{18-x}{3}\right)\right)}{7}$

Typing this equation into Wolfram Alpha, we get that $x \approx 3.90583$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\text{time}=\frac{\text{distance}}{\text{velocity}}$, the time to get from $A$ to the $x$-axis is $t_A=\frac15\sqrt{x^2+4^2}$ and the time to get from the $x$-axis to $B$ is $t_B=\frac17\sqrt{(18-x)^2+3^2}$, assuming $18$ means from base to base, not from peak to peak. So
$$t=t_A+t_B=\frac15\sqrt{x^2+4^2}+\frac17\sqrt{(18-x)^2+3^2}$$
Set the derivative to zero:
$$\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac x{5\sqrt{x^2+16}}-\frac{18-x}{7\sqrt{(18-x)^2+9}}=0$$
Rearrange to
$$\frac x{5\sqrt{x^2+16}}=\frac{18-x}{7\sqrt{(18-x)^2+9}}$$
The astute reader will recognize this as Snell's law, so calculus wasn't actually required. After squaring out, multiplying by the denominators, and simplifying, we have a quartic equation
$$24x^2(18-x)^2+441x^2-400(18-x)^2=0$$
Matlab finds the roots

```
 18.050671948833823 + 4.380818294467868i
 18.050671948833823 - 4.380818294467868i
 -4.007174210301167 + 0.000000000000000i
  3.905830312633520 + 0.000000000000000i
```

The last root is the only one that is positive and real, so we conclude that
$x=3.905830312633520$.